# What happens when Password setting is updated?

Tags: security, security-review

I am trying to improve our Salesforce Org Health Check score.

I have one setting "Password complexity requirement" where current value is "Must include alpha and numeric characters" and as per Salesforce value should be "Must include alpha, numeric, and special characters". Now if I change the setting, Does all users needs to update their password which must contain Alpha numeric character now? Or this setting will apply whenever user reset their password?

Comment: You can, however, force all users to change their password if you want to ensure better secure (this would be recommended) by going to Setup > Expire All Passwords. They'll still be able to log in, but will be forced to select a new password.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, this is another good thing to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update password policy this need not be required to change the password for all the users. When a password reset is done or  when user need to update the password or when new user is created then this will ask for all the required things that were set in password  policies.

So to answer straight  it is not required for all the users to update the password